# How to sort different queries with union all in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, union-all

I need to sort two queries differently and return the paged result.
Example:

```
select Q1.* from 
   (select t.data1,t.data2 from table t order by t.data1 desc) as Q1

union all

select Q2.* from 
   (select t.data1,t.data2 from table t order by t.data2 asc) as Q2

ORDER BY data1 asc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? What isn't working about the SQL you have provided us?

Comment: Exactly, executing this query throws the error: Invalid use of the NEXT option in the FETCH instruction.